# vb.net cannot access a disposed object when opening form

Tags: vb.net, forms, objectdisposedexception

I have a program that we use to run different reports. Based on the menu option chosen, I open the same form that lists the reports based on the menu option.
(There are also different options and functionalities in the program, not just one form).

When clicking a menu option, I have the following bit of code

```
Private Sub ReportsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As     EventArgs) Handles ReportsToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    FormLocation = "F_Legal"
    FormName = "Legal"
    PrepareForm(F_Select_Report)
End Sub 'ReportsToolStripMenuItem1_Click
```

Where F_Select_Report the form is that is opened.

```
Private Sub PrepareForm(formName As Form)
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    For Each Form In Me.MdiChildren
        Form.Close()
    Next

    formName.MdiParent = Me
    formName.Height = Me.Height
    formName.Width = Me.Width
    formName.Show()
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub 'PrepareForm
```

This bit is called, closing all other opened forms, and then open the form that is called.

This works fine on the first time I try and open a form, but on the second try, I get an error message saying

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

And then on the third try, it opens the form again.
How would I fix this up?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that you were going to use `Me.MdiChildren` and not `formName.MdiChildren`? A form that is not opened yet wouldn't have any MDI children AFAIK.

Comment: Is _F_Select_Report_ an instance of a form or is it the Class name of the form?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx) say then when you close a form it gets disposed. That's why it doesn't work the second time. You should keep the form open or create a new instance.

Comment: @VisualVincent My main form has a MenuStrip, from here they select a menu option. So I want to close all forms but the main form, as all forms have the same MdiParent.

Comment: @Steve F_Select_Report is a form

Comment: If it is a MDI child of your MDI main form then your loop destroys it (dispose) so you cannot use it until you create a new instance of it

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Close` implicitly calls `Form.Dispose`
So if the `formName` is an `MdiChild` it gets disposed in the `For Each` loop.
Then, on the next line your code attempts to assign to its `MdiParent` property and there the error occurs.
So you need to skip it when closing MDI children like this:

```
For Each Form In Me.MdiChildren
    If Not Form Is formName Then Form.Close
Next
```

Given your code I think it is better to close the children before showing the `F_Select_Report` form. I.e. move the `For Each` loop as is to the top of the `ReportsToolStripMenuItem1_Click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best/nicest solution, but found a solution to this.
Instead of 1 Sub that does both closes all open forms, and then opens the new one, I split it out over 2 Subs.

Close all open ones

```
Private Sub CloseAllForms()
    For Each Form In Me.MdiChildren
        Form.Close()
    Next
End Sub 'CloseAllForms
```

And then open the new form

```
Private Sub PrepareForm(formName As Form)
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        formName.MdiParent = Me
        formName.Height = Me.Height
        formName.Width = Me.Width
        formName.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub 'PrepareForm
```

Now it works as needed.